# Stop firing event SelectionChange (Intersect already used) if it intersects with another range

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to run a macro `Calendar_Advanced` if any cell is selected in column **M**.

**Problem:** If I select any cell in the same time with Range M:M , the event also fires, like if I selected all row.

```vb
Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
      
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M3:M" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
        Call Calendar_Advanced
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried to add to the If condition `And Selection.Cells.Count = 1`.

It works, but prevents multi selection (`Calendar_Advanced`) to run on column M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count the columns to make sure it is just M.

```
Private Sub worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M3:M" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
            Calendar_Advanced
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Great thanks , It works